# C++ String pointers

Tags: c++

In my previous app I had an object like this:

```
class myType
{
public:
 int a;
 string b;
}
```

It had a lot of instances scattered everywhere and passed around to nearly every function.

**The app was slow. Profiling said that 95% of time is eaten by the string allocator function.**

I know how to work with the object above, but not how to work with string pointers.

```
class myType
{
public:
 int a;
 string* b;
}
```

They told me to use pointers as above.

- How much faster is it with a string pointer?
- What is copied when I copy the object?
- How to the following using the class with the pointer:

Access the string value

Modify the string value without modifying the one in the object (copy?)

General things that change if I use string pointers?

Comment: Did you pass those `myType` instances around by value or by reference?

Comment: Finally a good case for a string reference. 
struct { int a; string& b; }

Comment: @kenny: holding strings by reference (or pointer) is probably the last resort. Controlling the lifetime of each instance can be PITA

Comment: If you want automatic memory management without copying the string content a bunch of times, how about using a `boost::shared_array<char>` to hold your character data?

Answer (score 6):

It will actually probably be slower - you still need to create and copy the strings, but now you have the overhead of dynamic allocation on top. My guess is that you are copying your objects around too much - whenever you call  a function, your myType objects should be passed as const references, wherever possible, not by value:

```
void f( const myType & mt ) {
    // stuff
}
```

If you actually need to change mt, you would have used a non-const reference - this is also less expensive than passing a value and returning a new value with modified fields.

Answer (score 3):

I think using a pointer like this is a bad idea. Instead, look at how your `myType` is being used instead. In particular, instead of this:

```
void foo(myType a)
{
    // ...
}
```

Consider this:

```
void foo(myType const &a)
{
    // ...
}
```

In the former case, a copy of myType needs to be created to pass to the function foo(), in the second, no copy is needed, since a reference is passed instead (it's marked as `const` so that you can be sure `foo()` doesn't try to modify it - giving you (almost)the same behaviour as the first method).

There are probably other things you could change, but my guess is that doing this would give you the most bang for your buck (and it's a pretty mechanical change, so hopefully not too much chance of problems being introduced)

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers, you also should be making sure any member functions of that class that pass a string are passing by const reference. For example, say your class constructor definition looks like this:

```
myType::myType(int a, string b)
```

Use this instead:

```
myType::myType(int a, const string& b)
```

So basically, go through all your function parameters throughout your project, and change `string` to `const string&`, and `myType` to `const myType&`. This alone should fix the majority of your performance issues.

Note: About dynamically allocating the string and passing as a pointer: This is not a good idea, as though it will lighten the performance load somewhat, you're going to be extremely vulnerable to memory leaks, which makes debugging a nightmare (in addition to being much more haphazardly destructive to your performance than running slow). As a general rule, I highly discourage passing naked pointers. There's almost always a better, safer alternative.

Comment: Using a raw pointer like this is probably a bad idea.  But dynamically allocating the string and passing a pointer doesn't at all preclude the use of smart pointers such as `boost::shared_ptr`, which basically takes care of the memory leak problem.

Comment: Well, memory leaks aren't the only problem that can occur when passing pointers everywhere. Accidentally assigning a pointer to another when the data should have been copied; editing the data from a passed pointer when it shouldn't be; operating on a pointer that can be null in rare instances; these are all simple mistakes that can cause major bugs that are extremely difficult to track down.